# E-Mail invites are lost; provide alternative way to invite people

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I sent a careers invitation to a friend few months back.

I learned yesterday that the invitation never arrived - it probably got caught in a spam filter.

The same *might* have happened for two other invitations I sent out.

I realize sending automated E-Mail to arbitrary addresses is very tough to do reliably. There should be an alternative way of sending invitations manually, like access tokens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We added a feature that allows you to share your invitations via a sharable link that pretty much covers that case. It's available on the invites page:

[image]

Comment: This looks great, thanks! If only now I could have some new invites to try out the feature...? :)

Comment: @Pekka - So granted. Use them wisely young Skywalker ;-)

Comment: I was able to get to this page once before, but now when I click the link in my email it's gone. I wanted to give out another invite.

Comment: @Noctrine - I sent you 5 more invites just to be sure, but also make sure you are logged in and there should be an invitations link on the right side of the "My Profile" page. If you are still having a problem, please email us (careers@stackoverflow.com) and we'll get you fixed up.