# What happened to my invites?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

My careers profile says I have 5 invites with 0 remaining, but I'm quite positive I've never invited someone before. On top of that, I don't see any display telling me who I invited and whether or not they accepted as detailed in the [screenshot on this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92281/e-mail-invites-are-lost-provide-alternative-way-to-invite-people).

[image]

Comment: Just to get the most obvious thing out of the way, can you double check that you are logged into careers with the account that uses the email address you received the message at?  You can see the email on this account when you edit your personal info (top most edit button) on your profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there was a bug, sorry about that... They were awarded but never showed up. We fixed this and you now have 5 invites in your account.